# how to update google map marker after API response in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

Markers are not properly updating in my flutter project.
issue: 1) during first response it works well, after refreshing the API markers are not updating. for example : in first API response I have List of few markers and second response I gets empty list then previous markers not clear from the map.

code written below.

```
  void setMarker() {
final data = locationData; //API response in locationData list.

oldMarkers.addAll(markers);
markers.clear();

data.forEach((element) {
  markers.add(
    Marker(
      // consumeTapEvents: true,
      markerId: MarkerId(element.sId.toString()),
      position: LatLng(element.latitude!, element.longitude!),

      // infoWindow: InfoWindow(
      //     title: '${element.name}', snippet: "${element.address}"),
      icon: MapMarkerIconUtil.getBitmapDescriptor(element.provider)!,
    ),
  );
});
updateMarker();
update();}
```

```
 void updateMarker() {
   var updates = MarkerUpdates.from(
     Set<Marker>.from(
       oldMarkers,
     ),
     Set<Marker>.from(
       markers,
     ),
   );
   GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance
       .updateMarkers(updates, mapId: mapController.mapId)
       .catchError(
     (v) async {
       print("Error");
       logger(v);
     },
   );
   update();
   // GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance.
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a github repo or something we can copy paste that reproduces the issue you are experiencing? That would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance.updateMarkers()` support removing markers or not.

But you should try adding a `setState((){});` after the removing your old markers from the markers list; So the Map rebuild it self again.

And i don't know in your 'update()' method but why it's getting called from the both the functions `setMarker()` and `updateMarker()`

Comment: I ma using Getx, In my code I have used GetBuilder and its support update method for refreshing the state.